# Solution of differential equation without using sums

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do we derive the solution of $y''=y$ without using sums? I know the solution is a trig function but i cant prove it

Comment: What definition of trigonometric functions are we allowed to use? If you object to using the series definition, you still need some definition to prove that the function defined that way obeys the ODE

Comment: Any definition you want

Comment: What do you mean by "without using sums"?

Comment: Without the series definition

Comment: The solution is NOT a trig function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also insert a zero,
$$
y''+y'=y'+y,
$$
so that using $v=y'+y$ you get a system of 2 semi-coupled first order ODE
$$
v'=v,\\
y'+y=v.
$$
The first one has the obvious solution $v=Ce^x$, and the second can be solved with standard techniques, like the integrating factor
$$
(e^xy)'=Ce^{2x}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the given equation with $2y'$ to get
$$2y'y''=2yy'$$
which is the same as
$$\frac{d}{dx}(y')^2=\frac{d}{dx}(y^2)$$
Integrate both sides, the result ist $y'^2=y^2+c$. Can you do the rest?

The final result is...

> $$y(x)=A\cosh(x)+B\sinh(x)=Ce^{x}+De^{-x}$$ for some $A,B,C,D\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Thank you very much my friend

Answer (score 0):

If we are allowed to use the definition for the exponential function:

$$g(x)=A e^x \\ h(x)=B e^{-x}$$

We know that:

$$g'=g \\ h'=-h$$

---

$$g''=g'=g \\ h''=-h'=h$$

---

Which means that any:

$$y=g+h$$

obeys:

$$y''=y$$

$$y(x)=A e^x+B e^{-x}$$